# Disable Download A Copy Based On Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-library

In SharePoint 2013 we want to only display the Download A Copy option to specific users.

How can we disable the Download A Copy option using permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Users with **Read only** Permission at Site Level , Library Level will not get Download option.

Users with **contribute access** Permission at Site Level , Library Level and Item Level will get Download option.

Answer (score 1):

You can either give those users `View Only` permissions, or you can use IRM (Information Rights Management) to restrict the document.

Users with the `View Only` permission level can only list items in a list/library.  They need the `Read` permission level to open them.  More information on the different permission levels [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx).

IRM can be used to help control and protect documents that are downloaded.  You can find more information on how to apply IRM to a library [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-Information-Rights-Management-to-a-list-or-library-3bdb5c4e-94fc-4741-b02f-4e7cc3c54aa1).